# How to speed up bulk updates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want update this mail in my table. created index for this column. but this update take more than 1hour, whether server is empty its need many time to update.Why it is very slow? I want update daily more than 2 million rows. How to speed up this query.

```
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sqkw@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='wefr@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dkfjgk@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='jkdfj@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='tyhr@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dsfdsf@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dfjs@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sdjf@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sfs@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='wef@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='srfsf@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sadsd@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='ggu@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='ft@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='cvsdf@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dvsd@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dsfswr@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sdgs@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='werwe@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='eg@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='geg@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='fvgdfs@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='ww1@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='ger@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sf@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='fgdeg@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='wfgwe@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='asd@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='dfg@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='3r@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='geg@gmail.com';
update table1 SET list='mm' where mail='sdvsd@gmail.com';
```

Comment: IN() is your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1
SET list='mm'
WHERE mail IN('sqkw@gmail.com', 'wefr@gmail.com', ...)
```

Comment: Its nice, but its also take same timing. It is daily updates. i want to spped up

Comment: This should be faster, unless maybe you have no indexes. In which case there's no way to speed it up short of buying faster hardware.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints :

1. Backup before doing anything.
2. DROP all indexes except `mail`
3. Change the table's engine to InnoDB
4. Run your UPDATE's
5. Change back engine to MyISAM
6. Recreate indexes.

This is the hardcore scenario. The mass UPDATE time with this will decrease to a few minutes, guaranteed. If not the case, your hardware is probably faulty. However other operations might take longer, I don't know much about your table.

Test the different options : either only changing the engine, or only DROP/recreate indexes.